# I want to use the most intuitive asynchronous design pattern and need functions, and proper naming

Tags: design-patterns

I need to create a base class that has an abstract function which can be asynchronous. I wouldn't normally be this concerned with getting the naming and functions right but my class is part of an SDK so I need it to be as easy to understand and as close to the community standard as possible.

So, as an example, consider a case where this function is overriden so that it receives data from some server.  The concrete class might look something like

```
//asynchronous
class TalkToServer : TaskBase {

   void override StartExecute(){
       Server s = new Server();
       s.HandleResponse += new ReponseEvent(GotResponse);
       s.AskTheServer();
   }

   void GotResponse(Server s){
       //do stuff with response
       base.NotifyTaskComplete();
   }
}

//this could also happen (synchronous)
class Example2: TaskBase {

   void override StartExecute(){
       //do stuff
       base.NotifyTaskComplete();
   }
}
```

So the only functions I have in my base class for handling dealing with asynchronous procedures are:

- StartExecute()  //called when ready to start the task execution
- NotifyTaskComplete()  //called by the concrete class to notify listeners that the task is completed

So my questions are

1. Are these names ok or are there better names?  I was thinking I could use "Commit" for NotifyTaskComplete because it is actually transactional and the base class does contain a Rollback function as well. Maybe StartExecute should just be Execute (Because the task won't always be asynchronous as shown in Example2)
2. Are there any other functions I need?  Have I messed up this design pattern somehow?  I have seen examples where people use an asynchronous object but I think it makes it less intuitive in this case.  I want to focus on the idea of doing a task, and not so much on the idea that it may have asynchronous features.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest events rather than abstract methods which should be overriden in order to handle incomming data or Complete stage.

```
event EventHandler<StartedEventArgs> Started;
event EventHandler<CompletedEventArgs> Completed;
```

Comment: Yes, I prefer events in general and I think this is a good idea.  In this case, Started could be an event for sure...but completed would be a function that you call at some point to notify listeners that the task is done.  Do you suggest I use a different name for the complete function...seeing as you thought it was an event, I can already see that my naming probably is not good.